# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider error with HTMLUnit

Tags: java

I am getting the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider error` even after importing the Web client jar files.

Please find the screenshot below.

[image]

Can any one help me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, `NoClassDefFoundError` happen when there is missing dependencies to your project. Note that there is other possibilities...

For more information on `NoClassDefFoundError` you might want to check this thread

[Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

In your case, as @Jens already mentionned, we can see in your referenced libraries that you are missing `httpclient.jar`

See the [http components of Apache](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) download page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `httpclient.jar` from apache to your classpath. You can download it [here](http://hc.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider` error indicates that `httpclient-4.0.3.jar` file is mission in your class path.

Configure it in your class path `Right click project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Excernal Jars -> select jar file`